# Prove that funcion satisfies the differential equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

let $\phi(u)$ be an arbitrary differentiable function of a real variable prove that the function $z(x,y) = x\phi(xy)$ satisfies the differential equation
$$x\frac{∂z}{∂x}-y\frac{∂z}{∂y} = z$$

I decided to calculate partial derivatives
$$\frac{∂z}{∂x} = \phi(xy) + x\frac{∂}{∂x}\phi(xy)$$
$$\frac{∂z}{∂y} = x\frac{∂\phi}{∂y}$$
let $u = xy$
$$\frac{∂\phi}{∂x} = \frac{d\phi}{du}\frac{∂u}{∂x} = \frac{d\phi}{du}y$$
$$\frac{∂\phi}{∂y} = \frac{d\phi}{du}\frac{∂u}{∂y} = \frac{d\phi}{du}x$$
Substitute
$$\frac{∂z}{∂x} = \phi(xy) + xy\frac{d\phi}{du}$$
$$\frac{∂z}{∂y} = x^2\frac{d\phi}{du}$$
Substitute it to the differential equation
$$x\phi(xy) + x^2y\frac{d\phi}{du} - x^2y\frac{d\phi}{du} = x\phi(xy)$$
$$0 = 0$$

that's it, thanks for the help

Comment: Where did the factor of $y^2$ come from in your second-to-last expression?

Comment: What do you know about $\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}-\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}$? With the knowledge about that, you won't need any substitutions, you can directly compute it.

Comment: @JohnBarber, thank you very much, as I understood the error was exactly in this, because without this it turns out 0 = 0. What is a valid identity

Comment: @MariusS.L., It seems like nothing if I didn't miss anything

Comment: Also, you shouldn't write *partial* derivatives of $\phi, $ which is a function of a single variable.

Comment: @AnneBauval, Do you mean that I should write $\frac{d\phi}{du}$ instead $\frac{∂\phi}{∂u}$?

Comment: Yes or simply $\phi'(xy).$ And not $\frac{∂\phi}{∂x}$ but $\frac{∂}{∂x}\phi(xy).$

Comment: @AnneBauval, Thanks, I'll take it into account